# VB EventBus Library

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, event-bus

I couldn't find any EventBus Library for Visual Basic. I found one but it is for C#. Is this a possible pattern in VB or I have to use another? Any recommended pattern for decoupling my classes?

Comment: If you found one in C#, you could either convert it, or build it and reference it.

Comment: I found a C# library but I was hoping something that is more of an out-of-the-box thing. I guess I'm out of luck. I guess I have to read and rewrite some 800 line code. *sobs internally*

Comment: Start with this: http://converter.telerik.com/